# Memory Leak Issue?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Can Anyone explain me the following image, that how can I do releasing within this block of code

[image]

why there is issue when some having another object and you are releasing, like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some_url_having_image_on_server"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];      
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

How would I do release and explain the cases, and don't pass me links, just explain in your own programming skill, I really want to clear some concepts of memory management, they ever make me crazy :-(

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

All Methods without an alloc are autoreleased. So the [UIImage imagedWithData:] will be automatically released at the end of the runloop.

Comment: so you means I should not release the image?

Comment: Yes that's the right way. You only need to release objects, which you create with alloc.

Answer (score 1):

Methods with `alloc`, `copy,`copyMutable`and`new` will return an object with a retain count of 1.
All other methods should return autoreleased object that you do not need to release unless you retain explicitly. This is so for all of apple object-c objects.

example:

```
// need to be released:
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *tempCopy = [temp copy];
NSString *newString [NSString new]; // which is the same are alloc, init.

[newstring release];
[tempCopy release];
[temp release];
```

Autoreleased objects:

```
// You don not release:
NSString *temp = @"some string";
NSString *temp2 =[NSString string];
```

If you really want to learn the concepts than you should really read these:

- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)
- [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/CopyFunctions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001149-CJBEJBHH)

Comment: Hate to break it to you @rckoenes but directly from the linked article:

>You own any object you create
>You create an object using a method whose name begins with
>“alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc,
>newObject, or mutableCopy).

So `alloc` is what drives ownership of `data` in the example given by the original post. Thus, it is what needs to be released. Commenting out `[image release];` and un-commenting `[data release];` would address the analyzer warning as he owns `data` but not `image`.

Comment: You're right, the article does  sey this, my book about objective-c specifies `init` to add the retain count, but that make no sens since the object is then already created.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: `UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];` and you can release whenever you want.

EDIT:

Also if you try to release created object without alloc method, your app will crash, because you didnt alloc and you didnt say to memory "this place is mine !", then your app will autorelease your object.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 basic rules when it comes to memory management in Objective-C:

1.If you own it, release it.

2.If you don’t own it, don’t release it.

3.Override dealloc in your classes to release the fields that you own.

4.Never call dealloc directly (except for the call to `[super dealloc]` in your `-dealloc` method)

As above you have a code 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
here you did not allocated anything, so you dont have the right to release it.

The above 2 points are most crucial .